# Facebook Credits - Test Users

Tags: testing, facebook-credits, facebook-test-users

I am having a problem with test users and Facebook Credits. I have created a test user and added it to 'Credit testers' in Apps > MyApp > Credits, but cannot go through the 'Buy Credits' dialog process using the test user. After entering payment information I am redirected back to a facebook error page with the error:

'An error occurred while processing this request. Please try again later.'

I haven't registered a company for Facebook Credits under Apps > MyApp > Credits. Do I have to in order to use Facebook Credits with test users? Facebook say it is optional and required for payouts - I don't need this for testing/development.

Any ideas?

Many thanks

Comment: Are you able to get it working at all? If you're trying to do this as an admin of the app you may see a better error message - is your callback being hit by Facebook?

Answer (score 0):

I would look into the jsons in requests and responses, perhaps those ones are bad formatted.